# How to set an Active filter as default and clear it if we needed in admin UI component grid

Tags: magento2.3, collection, uicomponent

I have tried 3 different ways to set a default filtering option(set entity value as current customer entity value) to my custom module's grid.

**1.using _renderFiltersBefore()**

```
protected function _renderFiltersBefore() //@codingStandardsIgnoreLine
    {
        $currentUserEntity = $this->_commonHelper->getCurrentUser()->getEntity();
        $this->getSelect()->join(
                ['cu' => 'aw_ca_company_user'],
                "main_table.submitter_id = cu.customer_id",
                ['company_id'=>'cu.company_id']
            )->where("main_table.entity IN (?)", $currentUserEntity);            
        parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
    }
```

**2.via addFieldToFilter()**

```
protected function _beforeLoad()
    {
        $currentUserEntity = $this->_commonHelper->getCurrentUser()->getEntity();
        parent::_beforeLoad();
        $this->addFieldToFilter('entity',['eq'=>$currentUserEntity]);
        return $this;
    }
```

**3.using filterUrlParams**

```
 <settings>
        <filterUrlParams>
            <param name="entity">0041</param>
        </filterUrlParams>
    </settings>
```

All these 3 methods are working in the same way.
When I load the page, all data is filtered based on this condition. I can only see data with entity as current entity value.

But here the issue is It is not possible to reset or go back to the old state of all items with this method. When I apply more filters, it is sorting the current value only. Could not see all data as before.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ***ui_bookmark*** table to set a default filter. You can modify the value of config field through code for setting a filter by default.

Comment: Hello, where exactly do you modify the config field of the ui_bookmark table? Is there a hook or something? Can you add a code example?

Comment: No. Simply added a function in the Helper file, to set the ui_bookmark config value. and that value is passed to the controller while loading the page.Each time when we set a filter, those attribute will be added to the ui_bookmark JSON values, so what we're done here, observed the difference and added that by code.

Comment: Do we have any reference how we are expected to deal with the ui_bookmark table data